# ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

Tags: php

verán tengo un menú al cual al darle **click** a cualquier de los ítem ejecuta una función **ajax**

```
<a href="#" onclick="influencia();"><strong>Influencia</strong> <span class="icon-dot"></span></a>`

esta es la función ajax

`function influencia(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "opc_menu/programas/influencia.php",
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(data) {
            $("#contenedor").html(data);
            //Id del contenedor para mostrar el archivo
        }
    });
}
}
```

al direccionamiento a influencia.php tiene q mostrarme una pagina en la cual se encuentras graficos hechos con highcharts.

tendre conflictos con las funciones. Ya hice una pruebas llamadno al archivo influencias.php usando la dirección 
`<a href="opc_menu/programas/influencia.php"><a/>` 
y funciona, pero con las funciones ajax no.

aqui selecciono una opcion sin highcharts y no me da error y me muestra el contenido[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui al seleccionar influencia.php que cuenta con la libreria highchars me da estos error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya revise mil veces si los **link** y los **script** están bien direccionamientos y si lo están. Por favor ayuda.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si fuera algún problema de orden de los js pues me diera error igual al acceder a mi archivo por l url...el problema viene desde el menú y la funcion ajax. 
Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: puedes agregar como llamas los archivos js. puede ser el orden

Comment: cuando te menciona que no está definido, quiere decir que no está bien llamado o, en su defecto, estás llamando a la librería de Highchart antes de llamar a Jquery. Siempre debes llamar primero a Jquery antes de llamar a cualquier otra librería.

Comment: * respecto a los archivos woff, tienes que definirlos como myçme aceptados en tu servidor (apache/iis()

Comment: muchas gracias segui tu consejo de poner el jquery arriba funcione

Comment: Sin ver cómo estás haciendo el llamado a los recursos, es difícil dar una respuesta. Por favor inclúyelo.